# Show <div> on user page if user page belongs to current user

Tags: theming, 8, users

I have made a page that displays information about a user, much like a profile page.

Now I want users to be able to edit their information, so I added a button using twig tweak in `user.html.twig`:

```
{% if logged_in %}
<div class = "row"> 
    <a href ="{{ drupal_token('current-user:edit-url') }}" class = "edit-profile-btn col-lg-12">
      <div>Edit profile</div>
    </a> 
</div>
{% endif %}
```

[image]

This works fine, however the button is displayed on every profile page. I want to hide the button if a user is viewing another user's page.

> Can this be done using an `{{ if statement }}` to check if the viewed page belongs to the logged in user?

Answer (score 1):

To do this right you will need to use this combination of tests.

Is the user logged in {% if logged_in %} ?

Does the user have the permission needed to edit their profile with {% if user.hasPermission('depends on your site setup') %}?

Is the owner of the node the same as the current user?  {% if node.ownerId  == user.id %}

NOTE: The snippets above are not tested.  You may have to tweak to get the correct info (e.g. getOwnerId SHOULD equal node.ownerId.. but twig may have a different opinion).

Comment: I tried any statement containing an `=` but it gives me errors. Could you maybe give some more explanation on how to use your answer? I tried something like `{% if user.current-user %}` but this didn't work also

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo on my part.  Corrected the = to == in the answer, which is the correct syntax.

Comment: Thanks, that did at least not give me an error. Can you help me tweak it further? As I am using the `user` node with a specific view (full), do I have to do anything different? I tried using `{% if user--full.ownerId == current-user.uid %}` but it still displays on every page.